# yii, how to return plain text to form's target (<form target="")

Tags: yii

I have the following HTML code

```
<div id="form_target"></div>

<form action="?r=index/login" target="#form_target"></form>
```

I want to return text from the actionLogin and show it in form_target. How to do that?

I have tried

```
$this->renderText($Respond);
```

but still failed. On the browser I got a new screen showing the returned text. I want the text inside the form_target.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `$this->renderText($Respond)` with `echo $Respond`. From the [API page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderText-detail) for `renderText()`

> Renders a static text string. The string will be inserted in the current controller layout and returned back.

Comment: I think the <form> tag's behavior keeps the page refreshing. How is <form>'s target working?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the <form> tag with <div> tag. So I submit form entries without <form> tag.
And I use ajax post request to submit the values.

I can not explain why even I use the  tag, the page keep refreshing upon getting result from controller.

So the modified html code is like this:

```
<div id="form_target"></div>

<div id="form">
  <input .../>
  <input .../>
  <input .../>
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="SubmitForm();"/>
</div>
```

and the SubmitForm() looks like this

```
SubmitForm()
{
  var data = $("#form *:input").serialize();

  $.post(
    url,
    data,
    function(data)
    {
      $("#form_target").html(data['respond_text']);
    },
    'json'
  );
}
```